# REST API key generation strategy

Tags: api, rest, authentication, jax-rs

I need to provide authorization and authentication for my REST APIs implemented using JAX-RS standard, which are meant to be consumed from mobile clients and some devices. I have multiple devices with unique device identification which can POST some data. Mobile clients are just using GET requests to display that data. I am more concerned about the POST part, where I want to authenticate the clients. Also, I would like to keep it simple. I am thinking of using a simple HTTP basic authorization over HTTPS, with an API key. My question is how do I generate this API key?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Found some nice articles that cleared my doubt about the generation of API keys and using them for authentication:

http://restcookbook.com/Basics/loggingin/
http://www.smartjava.org/content/protect-rest-service-using-hmac-play-20

Answer (score 13):

You could take a look into Shiro: http://shiro.apache.org It is a very nice framework to "secure" APIs (authorization, authentication and other things for security). You can implement a "basic authentication" to "login" your users (via a username/password), then provide them with an API key, which you can use to perform a "bearer token authentication" to allow them to access the resources of your API. To do that you would define what shiro calls "filters", which are defined over API resources... this is defined in a "shiro.ini" as the following:

```
[main]
authcBasicRealm = com.yourapp.shiro.UserAuthenticatorRealm
tokenValidatorFilter = com.yourapp.shiro.BearerAuthenticationTokenFilter
tokenValidatorRealm = com.yourapp.shiro.BearerAuthenticationTokenRealm

[urls]
/rest/hello/login/** = ssl[8443], noSessionCreation, authcBasic
/rest/hello/hello = ssl[8443], noSessionCreation, tokenValidatorFilter
```

You need to implement/extend some of the Shiro default filters to make them work with your DB to get your user authentication data, etc. The nice thing is that they provide many tools to handle security issues, e.g.: to generate API keys, to salt and encrypt, etc. Take a look on their tutorials, they are in general very good.

There are other frameworks, namely Java EE has support for security and also Spring provides support for security. Take a look at this very nice presentation by Mat Raible where he presents and demos these three frameworks: http://www.slideshare.net/mraible/java-web-application-security-denver-jug-2013

Comment: I do not want to use another framework for security. But, thanks anyway.

Comment: I understand... but if you want to manage all those different aspects of security in your web service (basic authorization over HTTPS, then generate and give key to users, then authenticate the key, etc.) you will probably be doing the type of operations I presented yourself... which I avoid to do myself, since I am no security expert, and prefer to rely on a framework designed to cope with those things. Java EE, Spring also have frameworks/libraries to deal with security if you are using one of those (I updated my answer with reference to those).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) for this. A UUID looks like this:

```
550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440000
```

There are libraries to generate UUIDs available in every programming language.

Comment: How the server will know what UUID the client generated and vice versa?

Comment: Ok, now I ask, how do I distribute the keys then?

Comment: UUIDs only have 128 bits, and depending on the generation method, there may be patterns to how they're generated, which an exploit could take advantage of.

Answer (score 0):

I am looking into this on my end as well, if I want to rely on the JAX-RS standards and keeping the application "pure" I would use the default authentication system that comes with the container (which is usually BASIC auth).

This means the container would need to perform the authentication and course level authorization like Java EE apps that follow the standard and not build workarounds (i.e. using Shiro).

However, if you want to use the concept of API tokens and such while keeping your application free from implementing the authentication system, you'd need to implement that work elsewhere i.e. the container.

Unfortunately, container based authentication would have to be container specific.  JAAS does not describe a standard container API to do authentication realms.  Even their tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbxj.html talks about Glassfish specific configuration.

If your organization is big enough, DataPower also suppports OAuth http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/1208_rasmussen/1208_rasmussen.html so you can probably use it to manage the authentication and pass the proper credentials to your application.  However. you still need to do something vendor specific.

It isn't a bad thing though, I would rather do this approach rather than polluting the application with its own authentication system, thus making things inflexible should the authentication system change.  e.g. SonarQube has it's own authentication system which does not support client side certificates.

Comment: another approach I am thinking but not sure how it would work (which is why I didn't add it as an answer) is using bouncycastle to generate a client side certificate for the user to login.